# Insert records if not exist SQL Server 2005

Tags: t-sql, insert, temp-tables

SQL Server 2005 Database. I have a temporary table with many records, these records are coming from an RSS feed and need to be inserted periodically. Some of the data will change, and some will remain the same. I only need to insert the 'new' records, and eliminate the chance of inserting redundant data resulting in duplicate records. How do I accomplish this?

Example, tempTable,

```
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO myTable
                (
                    row1
                    ,row2
                    ,row3
                )
            SELECT
                row1
                ,row2
                ,row3
            FROM @tempTable
        END
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is a `not exists` subquery:

```
INSERT  myTable
        (row1, row2, row3)
SELECT  row1, row2, row3
FROM    @tempTable temp
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    myTable
        WHERE   row1 = temp.row1
                and row2 = temp.row2
                and row3 = temp.row3
        )
```

Comment: Excellent, this is precisely the solution I had been looking for. Many thanks. I have 1 more question. What if the order of the rows was not signifigant? Would I have to exhaust all permutations in the where clause? E.g. Where row1 = temp.row1 or row1 = temp.row2 or row1 = temp.row3?

Comment: @Timothy: Yes, but a better way would be to normalize the table.

Comment: @Timothy: In fact No. The comparison is to determine whether a table row (not the columns called row1, row2, row3 etc) already exists containing the data you want to insert..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("If Not Exists(select * from stholidays where holiday='"+ dd + "') begin insert into stholidays values('" + dateTimePicker12.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker20.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker13.Text + "','" + mbk + "','" + dateTimePicker14.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker15.Text + "','" + lt + "','" + dateTimePicker16.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker17.Text + "','" + ebk + "','" + dateTimePicker18.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker19.Text + "','" + textBox105.Text + "','" + textBox106.Text + "','" + textBox107.Text + "','" + dd + "','" + textBox104.Text + "')end", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```