# want to update unmatching rows from table1 to table2 in sql

Tags: sql-server

I want to append the table *Info1* from table *Info* where the *Update_date* column does not match[image]

[image]

For e.g last three records of table Info should be added in Info1 table

E.g Records on '2015-12-25' should be added to Info1

Comment: It ID is your primary key it would probably be better to use that column for finding new records.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert records if not exist SQL Server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062980/insert-records-if-not-exist-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO info1(Name,Loc,Version_no,Update_date,update_time)
SELECT Name,Loc,Version_no,Update_date,update_time 
FROM info
WHERE cast(update_date as date) NOT IN (select cast(update_date as date) from info1);
```